# Is there a way in CSS to position something as a percentage of its own height?

Tags: html, css

What I want is a child div to have 60% of itself hanging off the bottom of the parent. I would like to use something similar to:

```
.child { bottom: -60% * selfHeight; }
```

I cannot use `transform: translateY(60%);` because I also need it to push down the next parent sibling. And `translateY` would not do that.

Is there a way to achieve this (cross-browser, IE11+, Safari (iOS/Desktop), Chrome, FF)?

Comment: Pushing down by 60% of its _width_ is as easy as `padding-top: 60%` (vertical padding is relative to the width of an element) but I can't figure how to solve your problem. Good one ^^

Comment: As you say, @FelipeAls, _vertical padding is relative to the width of an element_ so one approach might involve a combination of `transform: rotate(90deg)` and `padding-top: 60%`.

Comment: @Rounin Not if there's text in the box.

Comment: If the text is contained within a `<p>` or a `<span>` or another element, the internal element can be rotated in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent image for this case. Look at my [snippet on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/5ztc78eb/).

```
<div class="imgdiv">
  <img id="imgid" src="http://www.21tech.ir/wp-content/uploads/nc-efi-placeholder-180x180.png">
  <img src="http://www.dl.21tech.ir/img-upload/2016/12/95091702.jpg">
</div>



.imgdiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ef2121;
}

#imgid {
  width: 100%
}
```

If you resize the window, you can see that is responsive but you can make it solid.